# Tabs in TabLayout aren't available for click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I've got simple tabLayout within Fragment file which is CoordinatorLayout.
It works good, when user swipes, different Fragments are displayed.

**The problem is, tabs aren't respond for clicking, user cannot select particular tab,it has oportunity to swipe only**

Below I launch files containing XML, ViewPager2 adapter, and Fragment.java in which I've implemented mechanism for swiping.

For global, in MainActivity I've implemented toolbar, that's why in Fragment's TabLayout I'm using `margin top 50dp`.
I also lunch its code.

```
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout

        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MyApp.TabLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
 
    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"/>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|right">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/minusFab"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_circle_outline_24px"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/plusFab"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/plusFab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_24px"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/mainFab"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/mainFab"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/minusFab" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/mainFab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_less_24px"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I've configured all mechanisms responsible for tabs logic:

```
    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {


    public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        super(fragmentActivity);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0: return new FirstFragment();
            case 1: return new SecondFragment();
            case 2: return new ThirdFragment();
            default:
                return  null;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

And implementation in Fragment.Java

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

public MainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


    ViewPager2 viewPager2 = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager2.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity()));
    TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(
            tabLayout, viewPager2, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0: tab.setText("First");
                        break;
                    case 1: tab.setText("Second");
                        break;
                    case 2: tab.setText("Third");
                        break;
                }
        }
    }
    );
    tabLayoutMediator.attach();
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}
```

}

MainActivity Layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FragmentsWithTabs.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.FragmentsWithTabs.PopupOverlay">

            <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
                android:id="@+id/color_mode_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|end"
                android:text="Switch here"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="127dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="297dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've came with an answer. In this situation, ViewPager2 was expanded on all screen hence  overlapping clicks on TabLayout :)

So solution was simple, now MainFragment's ViewPager2 code looks like follows:

```
 <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="629dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add listener on tablayout to listen tab select event. Like,

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(
   new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
   @Override
   public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
      //here you can write code to change page of viewpager based on tab id.
      // like, viewpager.setCurrentItem(0);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

setOnTabSelectedListener is deprecated for the TabLayout, so you can use the following code

```
     tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
           // add your code
        }

        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
           // add your code
        }

        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
           // add your code
        }

    })
```